# SPOJ - acode - NZEC error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just discovered the SPOJ website and I submitted my first solution to a problem: Alphacode http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACODE/

The online judge responded with a NZEC error with the following code, I don't understand why. I selected Python 3.2.3 (functools.lru_cache appeared in Python3.2), I also tried to remove lru_cache and replace it by a memoize decorator, but same problem.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=10000)
def acode(s, i=0):
    if i == len(s):
        return 1
    if s[i] == "0":
        return 0
    res = acode(s, i+1)
    if i + 1 < len(s) and (10 * int(s[i]) + int(s[i+1]) <= 26):
        res += acode(s, i+2)
    return res

def main():
    i = input().strip()
    while i != "0":
        print(acode(i))
        i = input().strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    try:
        main()
    except:
        sys.exit(0)
```

You may test it with this command:

```
$ echo "123\n1111\n21\n0" | python3 acode.py
```

Note: I also submitted without the "try: except:" but I can't find the output log on the SPOJ website.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does NOT seem to give NZEC (at least now). But, **it bails out with WA code**.

But instead of using LRU Cache, if I explicitly roll down the array using Dynamic Programming, **it gets accepted**

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=10000)
def acode(s, i=0):
    if i == len(s):
        return 1
    if s[i] == "0":
        return 0
    res = acode(s, i + 1)
    if i + 1 < len(s) and (10 * int(s[i]) + int(s[i + 1]) ≤ 26):
        res += acode(s, i + 2)
    return res


def acode_second_try(s):
    n = len(s)
    f = [0 for i in range(1 + n)]
    f[n] = 1
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        if s[i] != '0':
            f[i] = f[1 + i]
            if 1 + i < n:
                if 10 * int(s[i]) + int(s[1 + i]) ≤ 26:
                    f[i] += f[2 + i]
    return f[0]


def main():
    i = input().strip()
    while i[0] != '0':
        print(acode_second_try(i))
        #print(acode(i))
        i = input().strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    try:
        main()
    except:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an NZEC error because the maximum recursion depth of the python runtime is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem!!
Because I had written almost the exact same code! :P

And @rabih-kodeih was right, it was because of the recursion depth was exceeded. I fixed this by

`sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)`

Using the `sys` library you can set the recursion limit!

Note: This also has its limits, it is possible that if the input value is high enough it can exceed the heap memory as well. So this solution works for this problem of SPOJ but use it with caution.